# Test for click event using Jasmine test suite

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, bdd, jasmine

I am using `jasmine` to test my application and right now no button exists in my code
 but i want to write a test in which i can check that whether a click event is fired or not.
 You can simply think that i want to fire click event without button .

Here is what i did

```
 scenario('checking that click event is triggered or not', function () {

    given('Sigin form is filled', function () {

    });
    when('signin button is clicked ', function () {
        spyOn($, "click");
        $.click();

    });
    then('Should click event is fired or not" ', function () {
        expect($.click).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: i don't think ..this needs jquery tag....removing it now...

Comment: i mean to say the question was tagged jquery... which i think your question is not related to.. so i removed the jquery tag....

Comment: @bipen keeping jquery tag is not harm I think. It might help the OP to get answer quickly.

Comment: I inserted the tag just because , i think any body can tell me the way to fire click event without any button in jquery without caring about jasmine and other tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I generally tend to do is `create a stub` and assign the event to the stub. Then trigger the click event and check if it was called

```
describe('view interactions', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        this.clickEventStub = sinon.stub(this, 'clickEvent');
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        this.clickEvent.restore();
    });

    describe('when item is clicked', function () {
        it('event is fired', function () {
            this.elem.trigger('click');
            expect(this.clickEventStub).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```